# Not getting the multiple words as text value of dynamic label if value is retrieved from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, ado.net

When I tried to set text property of a label in my code from value retrieved by SQLDataReader,  I found that if Datareader is retrieving more than one words than label on form is showing only first word from the whole sentence retrieved. Below is the code with which groupbox of my form displayed only one word as the text of label instead of database having multiple words string.
NOTE: Here i am creating labels dynamically, So Should I alter any property of the label manually??

```
Label[] lb = new Label[10];
        int j = 25;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            lb[i] = new Label();
            lb[i].Name = MySqlDataReader[i];
            lb[i].Text = MySqlDataReader.ToString();
            lb[i].Location=new Point(9,j);
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(lb[i]);
            j += 25;
        }
```

Please help me with the sloution so that I can see the whole string as the text of the label.

Comment: You may need to set the size of labels or set it as auto grow.

Comment: Yaa.. Done. Have to set AutoSize property as true at run time.
Thankyou David. :)

Answer (score 0):

just include the following statement in your code.

```
lb[i].AutoSize = true;
```